# SharePoint 2007 : document library's view is not displayed correctly

Tags: 2007, document-library

I'm working on my SharePoint site today and I noticed that one of my document library's view is not displayed correctly in the main content place holder of the page.
I just have the blue title of the document library.
I don't even have the blue toolbar !

The most amazing thing is that in Paris (France) the view is displayed correctly, but in Brussels (Belgium) the user cannot view all documents of the same document library. A blank page is displayed in the main content place holder !

What the hell is the cause of this behaviour ?
Does anyone have an idea to make my documents appear in the view for any country, any user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new view and see if the same problem occurs. Is it just that one view that has the problem?

Create another Document Library in the same site. Same problem?

Let someone in Brussels log in with an account belonging to someone in France. Let's see if it's identity related, location related, or maybe desktop/browser related?

Does the document library have unique permissions? Does it have items with item level security?

Are the French users not looking at Personal Views rather than Shared Views?